# Get Facebook profile picture without resizing in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph API to get Facebook details. But I am getting profile image as resized.

E.g.:

[image]

I tried changing _s to _n. But still am getting size of **180x134**. But original image size is `260 × 194`.

How can I get the original images without resizing in iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the exactly image size, you can try fql query

```
$fql="SELECT id, width, height, url, is_silhouette, real_width, real_height FROM profile_pic WHERE id=me() AND height=260 AND width=194";

$avt = $facebook->api(array(
                         'method'=>'fql.query',
                         'query' =>$fql,
                       ));
$avt = & $avt[0]['url'];
```

I am using php, you can learn more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/22/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/[page id/profile id]/picture?type=large
```

Comment: I want the original image.http://graph.facebook.com/[page id/profile id]/picture?type=large gives resized image only.